# Embedded map (iframe) not centered when displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm building a web page with multiple tabs / pills that show tables and maps pertaining to points in a database.  One of these tabs is a iframe location map.  By default, this tab is hidden (display set to none).  When the user clicks on the tab, the map should display.

The problem is that when you click the tab, the map is off centered.  I think this is because when the page loads, it loads the map element with a specific size.  When the tab is clicked, it then resizes the iframe to fill the page without panning the map.

How do I make it so that when I click the tab, the will load centered?

Here is a gif showing the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/51dwj.jpg

Here's a code snippet.

```
<div id="Location" class="occTabcontent">
<style>
                .embed-container {
                    position: relative;
                    width:900px;
                    height:450px;
                }

                .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container iframe {
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 0;
                        left: 0;
                        width: 900px;
                        height: 450px;
                    }

                small {
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: 40;
                    bottom: 0;
                    margin-bottom: -15px;
                }
            </style>
            <div class="embed-container" style="border: 1px solid #d4c7cf;height:450px">

            <iframe frameborder="0" title="MineralOccurrenceFeeder-Webmap" src="//yukon2.maps.arcgis.com/apps/Embed/index.html?webmap=d5ed3bcdb3be41e2a22364d549b6cc0f&amp;legend=true&amp;basemap_toggle=true&amp;zoom=true&amp;scale=true&amp;disable_scroll=true&amp;theme=light&center=@longDD,@latDD&level=12&amp;marker=@longDD,@latDD"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="mapLink"><a href="http://yukon2.maps.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=d5ed3bcdb3be41e2a22364d549b6cc0f&center=@longDD,@latDD&level=14&marker=@longDD,@latDD" target=" _blank">Open map in larger window.</a></div>
        }
        </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">  
        document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

        function openTab(evt, tabName) {
            var i, tabcontent, occTab;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("occTabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            occTab = document.getElementsByClassName("occTab");
            for (i = 0; i < occTab.length; i++) {
                occTab[i].className = occTab[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        } 
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure why it's overflowing like that, but if you just want to center the ```embed-container```  then ```margin: auto``` should work. Edit: I'd also try something like ```max-width: 100%``` on the iframe itself to constrain it.

Comment: Tried that to no avail.  It's still having the same issue as before.